# ag-grid - space between column header and first row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

There is a space between grid header row and first data row - how do i remove this? Thanks
My code:

```
<div>
        <ag-grid-angular style="width: 500px; height: 500px;" [headerHeight]="0" [rowData]="rowData"
          [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [rowMultiSelectWithClick]="true" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
          [floatingFiltersHeight]="0" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>
      </div>



    columnDefs = [{
    headerName: 'id', field: 'id', editable: true, suppressToolPanel: true, filter: false, hide: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'payrollcode', field: 'payrollcode', editable: true, suppressToolPanel: true, filter: false
  },
  {
    headerName: 'select', field: 'select', editable: true, suppressToolPanel: true, filter: true, cellRendererParams: { checkbox: true }
  }];
```

[image: grid]
Please find code for screenshot gird below.

```
 @Input()
  displayObject: Array<any> = [];
  @Input()
  title = '';

  columnDefs = [];
  calcHeight$ = of(30);
  loading$;
  rowData = [];
  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private calendarService: CalendarService,
    private injector: Injector,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private sdToastService: SdToastService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    Object.keys(this.displayObject[0]).forEach(key => {
      this.columnDefs.push({ headerName: key, field: key, sortable: true, filter: true });
    });
    // this.rowData.concat(this.displayObject);
    this.rowData = this.displayObject;
    console.log(this.rowData);

  }


 

      <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
      <ag-grid-angular style="width: 600px; height:300px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
```

I added the code for the grid in the screenshot.

Here is a screenshot showing better the issue:
[image]

```
import { Component, Injector, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { CalendarService } from '../calendar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-preview-calendars',
  templateUrl: './preview-calendars.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./preview-calendars.component.css']
})
export class PreviewCalendarsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  displayObject: Array<any> = [];
  @Input()
  title = '';

  columnDefs = [];
  calcHeight$ = of(30);
  loading$;
  rowData = [];
  constructor(
    public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private calendarService: CalendarService,
    private injector: Injector,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    Object.keys(this.displayObject[0]).forEach(key => {
      this.columnDefs.push({ headerName: key, field: key, sortable: true, filter: true });
    });
    // this.rowData.concat(this.displayObject);
    this.rowData = this.displayObject;
    console.log(this.rowData);

  }

}



  <div style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
      <ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs">
      </ag-grid-angular>
    </div>
```

You will see that the first row is occupies too much space and the last row is hidden - this is the issue it seems there is an empty row being displayed.

The data:

[image]

Comment: can you add the screenshot of the ***space*** you are referring to?

Comment: @sandeepjoshi - added screen shot - you see the header row - 0 , 1, 2 etc, and the first row starting at code provider etc. There is a space of about one row in between.

Comment: one thing i don't get is how come you have header 0 ,1,2 when you are setting property `[headerHeight]` to 0. also i am not able to recreate the said issue [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vcqGwohhDYxvp1BN?preview) . can you create a plunkr recreating the issue?

Comment: @sandeepjoshi - Hello - thank you for your help - actually the screenshot is from another grid than the ts-file code I pasted. It's my mistake - on the first grid I have set the headerHeight to 0 precisely because of the space issue. I added the screenshot to better illustrate the space. Anyway I will create a plunkr and hope to recreate the issue. Pls note that given my project is Angular 6 - ) I am using ag-grid 20.0.0

Comment: I added the code for the screenshot grid:

Comment: @sandeepjoshi Please find additional information in the edited post. Unfortunately could not do plunker cause Angular version there is 8

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I was embedding the grid in a prosemirror document. `white-space: break-spaces` is what broke `ag-grid`.

Setting `white-space: normal !important` fixed the header spacing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be caused by duplicate rows. Try adding a unique id for each element and adding `getRowNodeId: data => data.id` to the `gridOptions`.